# Routing in SlimFramework

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I follow a tutorial for SlimFramwork and I try to route through some pages that I defined. I have this index.php file from which I run:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

require_once('../app/api/books.php');

$app->run();

?>
```

and this file books.php which is my page:

```
<?php

$app->get('/api/books', function()  {
    echo "Welcome to books";
});

?>
```

This is my folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

I run this on localhost with wamp using this link:

localhost:8082/myslimsite/app/api/books

I got my localhost on port 8082, my php version is 7.0.10

This are my errors

[image: Errors]

I try to find on the internet solution but nothing works, something that I found and tried was:

1 - For books to use ($app) like this:

```
<?php

$app->get('/api/books', function()  {
    echo "Welcome to books";
});

?>
```

2 - In books to use the file with the class that have $app variable

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;
```

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: the question is : why do you need to separate your routes like this? put all of your routes in one file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: It is unlikely that the code you posted creates the error message you get. Please check again that your posted code is exactly what you see in your files. This is likely a typo inside one of the files.

Comment: The posted code is the exact one that I use.
This is the tutorial that I follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0V9vj2lYUY&index=3&list=PLBEpR3pmwCayt4DR0UbhMgCfxHQWi0RCQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is not correct 
You must navigate first to index.php then to your route

IF your server home page is index.php in the public folder 
You will only navigate to your route url directory **NOT** to the path for This file 
Otherwise  you must navigate to **public/*Your-Route-Url***

So Navigate to

```
localhost:8082/myslimsite/public/api/books
```

This will Work correctly